# Can't delete a grand parent node in BST program

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

This Binary search tree program crashes when i try to delete a node having grand children.
Such a node is "80". I can delete any other node successfully and do other operations like traversal, Finding height and finding minimum or maximum element.
Please look at the code and tell me if i need to provide any other information.

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *left, *right;
};
struct node *root=NULL;
int main()
{
root=insert(root,100);
insert(root,80);
insert(root,10);
insert(root,40);
insert(root,90);
insert(root,30);
insert(root,120);
insert(root,140);
inorder(root);
printf("Min: %d  Max: %d\n",    FindMin(root),  FindMax(root));
delete(root,80);
printf("After deletion:\n");
inorder(root);
return 0; 
}
struct node *insert(struct node *node, int data) 
{
if(node==NULL) 
{
    return newnode(data);
}
else if(data < node->data)
{
    node->left=insert(node->left, data);
}
else if(data > node->data)
{
    node->right=insert(node->right,data);
}
return node;
}
struct node *newnode(int data)
{
struct node *tmp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
tmp->data=data;
tmp->left=tmp->right=NULL;
return tmp;
}
struct node *inorder(struct node *root)
{
if(root!=NULL)
{
 inorder(root->left);
 printf("%d\n",root->data);
 inorder(root->right);  
}

}
struct node *FindMin(struct node *root)
{
if(root==NULL)
{
    printf("Tree is empty!\n");
    return -1;
}
while(root->left!=NULL)
{
    root=root->left;
}
return root->data;
}
struct node *FindMax(struct node *root)
{
if(root==NULL)
{
    printf("Tree is empty!\n");
    return -1;
}
while(root->right!=NULL)
{
    root=root->right;
}
return root->data;
}
struct node *delete(struct node *root, int data)
{
if(root==NULL)
{
    printf("Tree is empty!\n");
    return -1;
}
else if(data < root->data)
{
    root->left=delete(root->left, data);
}
else if(data > root->data)
{
    root->right=delete(root->right, data);
}
else
{
    if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
    {
        free(root);
        root=NULL;
    }
    else if(root->left==NULL)
    {
        struct node *tmp=root;
    //  tmp=root;
        root=root->right;
        free(tmp);
    }
    else if(root->right==NULL)
    {
        struct node *tmp=root;
        //tmp=root;
        root=root->left;
        free(tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *tmp=FindMin(root->right);
        root->data=tmp->data;
        root->right=delete(root->right,tmp->data);
    } }
   return root;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your findMin function is defined to return `struct node *` however you are returning the `int` value defined in the found node's `data` not actually a `struct node *`. C allows this, so it's not picked up when you compile.

Comment: return (struct node*)root->data;  It's not working still why?

Comment: @LetmeLearn0089 - it's a legal cast, but `data` never was intended to be a `struct node *` - that is probably the problem. You then assign the value returned from `findMin` to `right`, think carefully about what you expect to happen when you try to use that `right` after that assignment.

Comment: OK. found it. Need to return root only, but i was casting int to pointer.    Thanks everyone! :D